# Flexslider Callbacks not firing on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, ios, callback, stylesheet, flexslider

I'm using the Flexslider callbacks to trigger stylesheet changes. Working great on desktop for all modern browsers but not on ios devices -- it seems to ignore the after callback function. The full code for the Flexslider is below 3 slides - 3 stylesheets, they basically just change the colors of certain elements on the page.

```
$(window).load(function() {
//Home Gallery Flexslider
$('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",
    pauseOnHover: false,
    directionNav: false,
    slideshowSpeed: 15000,
    slideshow: true,
    touch: true,
    animationSpeed: 0,
    controlNav: true,
    keyboard: true,
    manualControls: ".flex-control-nav li",
    start: function(slider){
        $('#slider').fadeIn('slow');
        $('link[title=resource]').prop('disabled',true);
        $('link[title=apps]').prop('disabled',true);
        $('link[title=shop]').prop('disabled',false);
    },
    after: function(slider){
        if(slider.currentSlide==0) {
            $('link[title=shop]').prop('disabled',false);
            $('link[title=resource]').prop('disabled',true);
            $('link[title=apps]').prop('disabled',true);
        }
        if(slider.currentSlide==1) {
            $('link[title=apps]').prop('disabled',false);
            $('link[title=shop]').prop('disabled',true);
            $('link[title=resource]').prop('disabled',true);
        }
        if(slider.currentSlide==2) {
            $('link[title=resource]').prop('disabled',false);
            $('link[title=shop]').prop('disabled',true);
            $('link[title=apps]').prop('disabled',true);
        }
    }
});
});
```

I have narrowed the issue to specifically the after callback function because using before triggers a reaction ( not a correct one ) but a reaction. Thank you for any help that can be given.

Comment: I updated the Flexslider to the latest build from Github (2.2.2) and it fixed my issue with the after callback - however the touch gesture is now not working properly. Trading one issue for another.

Comment: Figured it out! I was using the min file and for grins ad giggles decided to try the full js file and it works the callbacks and the touch both now function. I hope this helps anyone with the same issues I was having.